# How to change the color of a:visited to its parent color on refresh of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to change the color of the a:visited to its parent color on refresh. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
   .foo:visited {
    color: #f00;
 }

 document.getElementById('yourID').className += ' foo';
```

I hope this will help you